# Microsoft Graph API Update Schema Extension

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I created a schema extension over the graph explorer. Now I want to update the extension and a new value also with graph explorer. But on update I get the error:

```
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Cannot delete an existing property."
```

Creation Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions/$entity",
    "id": "id_DevTests",
    "description": "DevTests",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Group"
    ],
    "status": "InDevelopment",
    "owner": "myappidd",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "NewProp1",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

For updating I used the following request

`Patch: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions/id_DevTests`

```
{
  "owner": "same app id",
  "description": "DevTests",
  "targetTypes": [
    "Group"
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "AddProp",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ],
}
```

Error from Graph:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Cannot delete an existing property.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b1d5c1ef-b037-4c41-b46e-174e8b3218c6",
            "date": "2019-09-10T17:52:20"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the part that explains this

> Only the app that created a schema extension (owner app) can make
>   additive updates to the extension when the extension is in the
>   InDevelopment or Available status. That means the app cannot remove
>   custom properties or target resource types from the definition. The
>   app can, however, change the description of the extension.

from the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Getting this error even when am the application owner.  Happens when there is a resource field (user, etc.) that has a value already set for one of the schema extension properties.  In progress finding the solution